# Searching and Sorting in Jquery DataTable for my Django app, PostgreSQL DB is not working

Tags: python, django, datatables, jinja2

I am using Jquery DataTable and in my Django app where I am getting data from the PostgreSQL DB. I am able to get the data into the table but I cannot get the table to sort and search.

`datatables.js`:

```
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable();
});
```

`index.html`:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Testing Type</th>
          <th>Question</th>
          <th>Difficulty Level</th>
        </tr>
   </thead>
   {% for qiq in qa_interview_questions %}
   <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ qiq.testingtype }}</td>
        <td>{{ qiq.question }}</td>
        <td>{{ qiq.difficultylevel }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  {% endfor %}
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Somehow the Search and Sorting in the DataTable does not work at all. It works if I hardcore the data.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `<tbody>` HTML tag should be outside of the Django `for` loop tag, might not be your issue but having repeated `tbody` tags might cause some issues

Comment: if i move `<tbody>` above `for` loop it throws error. I am able to get the data.

Comment: What error? You'll need to move `</tbody>` to after `{% endfor %}` too

Comment: yes, i moved </tbody> to below {% endfor %} too
url: shorturl.at/nGNS7

Comment: What is the error? An error is better than not working at all

Comment: ohh cool that works. Thank you @IainShelvington. I cleared the cache and its working.

Moving <tbody> HTML tag  outside of the Django for loop tag.